# How do I repeatedly append or add html in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have code that uses `.repeat()` to inject a string a number of times based on the input number given.

But I want to inject characters/symbols, and/or elements that use html specifically to get the styling I want. In this case, I want to produce a number of circles to indicate a level of skill.

As you can see, I got a string to work in the repeat() function, but I want to repeat html instead.

This is a snippet from a react app. I don't want to use the ">" symbol as the repeated unit, I want to repeat something more complex like a div or a font awesome icon.

```
displayDevSkill = () => {
  return Object.values(this.state.skills).map(skill =>
    <div className="skill">
      <Fade><div className="skill-level">{this.skillLevelMeasure(skill.level)}</div></Fade>
      <div className="skill-leveltitle">{skill.leveltitle}</div>
      <div className="skill-title" id={skill.id}>{skill.title}</div>
      <i className={skill.icon}></i>
    </div>
  )
}

skillLevelMeasure = (level) => {
  let unit = ">"
  return unit.repeat(level)
}
```

I want to have something like repeated circles or html elements.

Comment: `repeat()` is a method of the String class.  It will repeat anything you want, including a string containing HTML.  e.g. `"<span>whatever you like</span>".repeat(2)`

Comment: YOu can use lodash _.times to achieve the same.

Comment: repeat() with the html in it doesn't work. I am not sure why.